# C++ pow function get a weird result

Tags: c++

Using some version of minGW, the following code will print 99.

```
int high;
high = pow(10,2);
std::cout<<high<<std::endl;
```

The parameter of pow function is double, but why i get 99? Someone who can tell me the process hidden inside pow function ?

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings. That will give you a clue. Second clue: "What every computer scientist should know about floating point."

Answer (score 4):

Converting a double to an integer truncates the fractional part. `pow(10,2)` produces a slightly inaccurate result; if it's slightly high, you'll get 100 and if it is slightly low you'll get 99.

Moral: if you mean `i*i`, write `i*i`.